# How to change document without changing location?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I tried to load entire page by ajax (doctype and html tags removed). And then

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

But Google Chrome says: **An invalid or illegal string was specified.**

The same error if I do:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML='<head><meta></head><body></body>';
```

But it's ok with this string:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML='<head></head><body></body>';
```

Comment: How about `location.reload()`?

Comment: I have edited the title of the question. I want to change entire document to a new docement from other location. But without changing url in the address bar.

Comment: Please take a closer look to the HTML you create with the last code snippet. It just adds the tags in the `head` section, and the original `body` is not touched at all. Also adding `meta` tags to a page in a way or another is worth of nothing, newly added `meta`s have no affect to the page after the `head` has been parsed once. In IE `document.documentElement.innerHTML` is read-only... You need to add/remove stylesheets, add scripts if needed (using proper DOM methods), and rewrite the `body` content to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Of course you'll need to include the html tag and doctype.

Comment: Object #<Document> has no method 'write'

Comment: Is your page in xhtml ? Your first string isn't valid xhtml, nor does document.write work.